# Can I access the href of my ajax request in the javascript of my request?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Here a sample use case:

I request a simple form via an ajax request. I want to submit the result to the same page that I requested. Is there a way to access the URL of that request in the resulting request's javascript?

Below is some code that accomplishes what I want via javascript AND PHP. The downside to this is that I have to include my javascript in the same file as myajaxform.php. I'd rather separate it, so I can minify, have it cached etc.

I can't use location.href, b/c it refers to the window's location not the latest request.

```
frm.submit(function () {
    if (frm.validate()) {
        var data = frm.serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : '<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>',
            type : 'POST',
            data : data,
                dataType: "html",
            success : function (data) {

            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

If there's not a way to access it via javascript directly, how would you solve this problem so that the javascript can go in it's own file? I guess that I could in the original ajax request's success handler, create some sort of reference to the URL. Thoughts? Maybe something using the jQuery data method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the url to submit to in the `action` attribute of the form, and then set the `url` to `frm.action`:

```
jQuery.ajax({
             url : frm.action,
             type : 'POST',
             data : data,
             dataType: "html",
             success : function (data) {
            }
});
```

Comment: ah, yes ... simple, obvious answer. just <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" first ... :P

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I totally misinterpret your question, as I find it somewhat confusing. What about

```
frm.submit(function () {
    if (frm.validate()) {
        var data = frm.serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
            url : window.location.href,
            type : 'POST',
            data : data,
            dataType: "html",
            success : function (data) {

            }
    });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: window.location.href would refer to the window's location, not the URL of the ajax request ... thx though